# If Matthew thought Jesus was God why does he have a genealogy?

Tags: matthew, jesus

If Matthew believed Jesus is God and was the ‘word’ and existed before the world was created, why does he have a genealogy for Jesus in Matt 1?

Matt 11:28 - 28 “Come to me, all you who are weary and burdened, and I will give you rest.

Matt 28:18  - Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me.

Matt 22:44 “‘The Lord said to my Lord, “Sit at my right hand, until I put your enemies under your feet”’?

Matt 26:64 "You have said it yourself," Jesus answered. "But I say to all of you, from now on you will see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of Power and coming on the clouds of heaven."

Psalm 110:1 - The LORD said to my Lord: "Sit at My right hand until I make Your enemies a footstool for Your feet."

Comment: I can't really figure out what you're asking - these three texts all appear to say the same thing? What do you mean by acceptable? To whom? Is this a question about any of these specific texts, or their author's viewpoint, or a more philosophical/moral conundrum that the texts don't mention?

Comment: yes I see your point amended

Comment: @Stevecanhelp - not sure maybe this should be deleted and another Q asked - let me know what you think is best.  Obviously, Dottard has answered.  Not sure if he is happy to delete his answer

Comment: I'm not sure I really see a hermeneutical angle to the question - a genealogy is a genealogy. It contains the people who are in that lineage. Asking why Matthew or Luke included a genealogy in light of a personal moral issue a reader may have with the text just sounds like speculation to me - it's all speculation and opinion.

Comment: I'd suggest having a read through all the other titles of the 'Jesus genealogy' questions (there are a few!), strip back all your theological assumptions, focus on the text itself, and think about what you're really asking about the text, its author or recipients. I'll amend the closure to 'needs more focus'.

Answer (score 2):

One of the (several) functions of genealogy in Matthew 1 is to illustrate grace.  The OP has pointed out of the many examples - marital incest between Judah and Tanar.  Here are some further examples:

- Salmon married a prostitute, Rahab, and produced Boaz
- Ruth was a foreigner, a moabitess, who were not permitted to join Israel until the tenth generation, Deut 23:3
- David had Solomon by Bathsheba, the wife of Uriah whom David power raped and murdered Uriah and then lied about it
- Abraham had married his half-sister, an illicit marriage under Torah law
- Jacob married sisters, also illegal under Torah law

The LORD's grace is very great.  Jesus came from this line of "sinners".  I am sure that, if the record were more complete, there would be many more nasty people in the genealogy.

Comment: Ruth _was_ the tenth, or possibly even later, generation, so her marriage to Boaz was _legal_.  Abraham's marriage preceded the Torah law, so was not governed by it.  Jacob's marriage of sisters also preceded the giving of the Torah law, and was not governed by it.  Most of your points are invalid, being unsupported by scripture.

Comment: @Biblasia - on what basis was Ruth the tenth generation, and from what?

Comment: If God is going to say something like "tenth" generation, it must have a starting point. The starting point is with Lot's children, in this case Moab.  While we do not have all of the generations on that side recorded, we do have the equivalent generations on Abraham's side recorded and need simply to compare across. Moab was born before Isaac.  Isaac, Jacob, Judah, Pharez, Esrom, Aram, Aminadab, Naasson, Salmon, Boaz --> that's ten generations.  Isaac did not have children until he was sixty; Jacob was 92 for Levi, who was older than Judah. It's unlikely Moab's line waited so long.

Comment: @Dottard—Agree with @Biblasia about the Torah not governing Jacob and Abraham. We all know that Adam and Eve's children married their own siblings. The Torah (the Law of Moses) simply didn't exist until it was given to Moses at Sinai, and “for where there is no law there is no transgression” (Rom. 4:15).